# Complementos pre-existentes no funcionan después de comenzar a partir de un perfil personalizado Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

Tengo Un Codigo En C# Con Selenium Muy Simple Solo Es Controlar Una Extension VPN Y Navegar A X Pagina.

La Cuestion Es Que Despues Que Selenium Inicia Con EL Perfil Personalizado De Firefox Desaparece Las Extensiones Que Tiene Instaladas El Perfil Por Lo Cual No Me Permite Controlar Las Extension VPN.

En Mi Maquina Funciona Correctamente El Problema Es Al Ejecutarlo En Otra Maquina.

```
FirefoxProfile profile1 = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\Familia\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6r8313wg.1");
            FirefoxOptions options1 = new FirefoxOptions();
            options1.Profile = profile1;                
            FirefoxDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver(options1);
            driver1.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            do
            {

                driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("moz-extension://3667138c-f19d-49a2-8ffe-278b50c1e52c//popup.html");
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                IWebElement VPN15 = driver1.FindElement(By.ClassName("server-item__server"));
                VPN15.Click();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                driver1.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
                Thread.Sleep(70000);
             } while (!i.Checked);
               driver1.Quit();
```